# PDO is not passing html tags

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am using PDO and insert message in database using pdo but html tags is not passing.My db connection is with utf-8 charset my form and database is also.
Please see  the code below how can i add html special tags in db using pdo .

```
      $query="INSERT INTO `message`(message) VALUES ('$message')";
      $dbc = dbc::instance();
      $result = $dbc->prepare($query);
      $result = $dbc->execute($result);
```

Comment: `PDO` knows nothing about your html tags. Check `$message` value and prepare for sql-injection.

Comment: It is most probably breaking the query because `$message` has a `'` in it. Please read up on how to use `prepare` statements correctly.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: It generally helps if you [look at what the database has to say about non-working SQL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: i will fix later about security first i need to solve this html tag issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point and power of prepared statements - you are still including a variable directly in the sql statement despite using a prepared statement. The following is not tested obviously but it should ( ? ) be ok - hopefully

```
  $message=$_POST['message'];

  $query="INSERT INTO `message` ( `message` ) VALUES ( :message );";
  $dbc = dbc::instance();
  $stmt= $dbc->prepare( $query );
  $result = $stmt->execute( array( ':message'=>$message ) );
  if( $result ){
      /* ok */
  }
```

Apologies, I wrote that too hastily - I think the changed version ought to be ok now.

Comment: not working . When i add $message=$_POST['message']   then query will not executed